# Symfony - Data file for "root" was not found. error

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Something gone wrong with my server. So my hosting provider uploaded backup copy of my Symfony site. The site is working, you can login and etc. But when you login and click "Go to administration!" it gets - **500 | Internal Server Error | sfException** - **Data file for "root" was not found.**

Site is using symfony v.1.4.15 - php 5.3.27

Here is the whole stack trace:

```
at ()
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/i18n/sfCultureInfo.class.php line 302 ...
      if (is_file($filename) == false)

      {

        var_dump($filename);

        throw new sfException(sprintf('Data file for "%s" was not found.', $file));

      }


      if (in_array($filename, $this->dataFiles) == false)
at sfCultureInfo->loadCultureData('root')
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/i18n/sfCultureInfo.class.php line 216 ...
at sfCultureInfo->__construct('bg_BG')
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/i18n/sfCultureInfo.class.php line 136 ...
at sfCultureInfo::getInstance('bg_BG')
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/i18n/sfDateTimeFormatInfo.class.php line 186 ...
at sfDateTimeFormatInfo::getInstance('bg_BG')
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/i18n/sfDateFormat.class.php line 100 ...
at sfDateFormat->__construct('bg_BG')
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/helper/DateHelper.php line 57 ...
at format_date(1484310234, 'F', null, null)
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/helper/DateHelper.php line 65 ...
at format_datetime(1484310234)
in SF_ROOT_DIR/apps/backend/modules/default/templates/_header.php line 50 ...
at require('/www/simplyshopping.eu/www/apps/backend/modules/default/templates/_header.php')
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/view/sfPHPView.class.php line 75 ...
at sfPHPView->renderFile('/www/simplyshopping.eu/www/apps/backend/modules/default/templates/_header.php')
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/view/sfPartialView.class.php line 124 ...
at sfPartialView->render()
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/helper/PartialHelper.php line 157 ...
at get_component('default', 'header', array())
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/helper/PartialHelper.php line 115 ...
at include_component('default', 'header')
in SF_ROOT_DIR/apps/backend/templates/layout.php line 12 ...
at require('/www/simplyshopping.eu/www/apps/backend/templates/layout.php')
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/view/sfPHPView.class.php line 75 ...
at sfPHPView->renderFile('/www/simplyshopping.eu/www/apps/backend/templates/layout.php')
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/view/sfPHPView.class.php line 146 ...
at sfPHPView->decorate('')
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/view/sfPHPView.class.php line 196 ...
at sfPHPView->render()
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/filter/sfExecutionFilter.class.php line 155 ...
at sfExecutionFilter->executeView('default', 'index', 'Success', array())
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/filter/sfExecutionFilter.class.php line 116 ...
at sfExecutionFilter->handleView(object('sfFilterChain'), object('defaultActions'), 'Success')
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/filter/sfExecutionFilter.class.php line 54 ...
at sfExecutionFilter->execute(object('sfFilterChain'))
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/filter/sfFilterChain.class.php line 53 ...
at sfFilterChain->execute()
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/filter/sfBasicSecurityFilter.class.php line 72 ...
at sfBasicSecurityFilter->execute(object('sfFilterChain'))
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/filter/sfFilterChain.class.php line 53 ...
at sfFilterChain->execute()
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/filter/sfRenderingFilter.class.php line 33 ...
at sfRenderingFilter->execute(object('sfFilterChain'))
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/filter/sfFilterChain.class.php line 53 ...
at sfFilterChain->execute()
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/controller/sfController.class.php line 238 ...
at sfController->forward('default', 'index')
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/controller/sfFrontWebController.class.php line 48 ...
at sfFrontWebController->dispatch()
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/util/sfContext.class.php line 170 ...
at sfContext->dispatch()
in SF_ROOT_DIR/root/backend.php line 7 ...
```

Comment: Are you sure this is Symfony 2? The exception name looks more like Symfony 1.4. Also people will need more information then this stack trace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange symfony i18n error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809852/strange-symfony-i18n-error)

Comment: It's using v.1.4.15.